# Relationship Parsing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am having a df with two columns **col_1** and **col_2**. The entries in **col_1** are related with entries in **col_2**. It is some sort of relationship where A belongs to B, and B belongs to C & D, therefore A belongs to B, C and D.

```
import pandas as pd
col_1 = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "I", "J", "C", "A"]
col_2 = ["B", "H", "C", "D", "J", "L", "E", "Z"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1":col_1, "col_2":col_2})
df.sort_values("col_1", inplace=True)
```

**df**

[image]

I want to extract the relationship by keeping the **first occurring key** as the "my_key" and all other keys in "Connected" column.
How can I fetch all keys which are connected to each others ,keeping the conditions in mind.

- *The keys that are in col_1 should not be in the list of col_2*

and

- *Only the related keys should be in front of my_key*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `networkx` with [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html) for dictionary:

```
import networkx as nx

# Create the graph from the dataframe
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from(df[['col_1','col_2']].itertuples(index=False))

connected_components = nx.connected_components(g)
# Find the component id of the nodes
node2id = {}
for cid, component in enumerate(connected_components):
    for node in component:
        node2id[node] = cid + 1
```

Then get first values of groups to column `col_1` and map all another values in lists:

```
g1 = df['col_1'].map(node2id)
df1 = df.loc[~g.duplicated(), ['col_1']]

s = pd.Series(list(node2id.keys()), index=list(node2id.values()))
s = s[~s.isin(df1['col_1'])]
d = s.groupby(level=0).agg(list)

df1['Connected'] = g1.map(d)
print (df1)
  col_1           Connected
0     A  [C, B, E, H, D, Z]
4     I              [J, L]
```

For plotting use:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(g, scale=20)
nx.draw(g, pos, node_color='lightblue', node_size=500, with_labels=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Any way to plot these as a graph ?

Comment: @user110244 - Added solution, only is necessary rename second groups `g` to `g1` in `g1 = df['col_1'].map(node2id)` and `df1['Connected'] = g1.map(d)`

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is Networkx work well with very large dataset ? Any alternative in case not suitable for very large data ?

Comment: @user110244 Not sure, but I guess not working very fast in large data. Unfortunately not sure about alternatives, but I guess some people in StackOveflow should help.

Comment: It is giving an error  'Graph' object has no attribute 'duplicate'.

Comment: @user110244 - Do you rename `g` to `g1` ? like say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60375556/relationship-parsing/60375953#comment106804598_60375953 ?